# What issues coldfusion UI tags have

Tags: coldfusion, cfform

I have heard many times senior developers asking not to use coldfusion UI tags and that they cause problems. But can someone let me know what kind of problems it creates? I do not use CFML UI tags mostly, but some of the legacy code has them already. So if I have to change them, I need to convince people why they need to be changed. Reasons...

**Edit:**
I know this has been put on hold, but what I was asking about few points, a list kind of. So when I am talking with someone a client, fellow developer and want to emphasize the reason for not using cfform, I do have those reasons. With lot of good and some not so good answers, I reckon I can put up a list
1) They use old outdated versions of JavaScript libraries and HTML.

2) They have caused security issues in the past.

3) They get in the way of knowing how things actually work.

4) ColdFusion UI does work currently. However, the issue people have is simply, technology changes. It's simple as that really. jQuery and other UIs are constantly changing. Along with a lot of other APIs that ColdFusion UI uses. This means, if you are using ColdFusion 10 today and 5 years from now you are on ColdFusion 13 you may have issues with your ColdFusion 10's UI.

5) Another example is .  had an issue recently because it uses google maps and google updated their API. Since the update took place it broke the tag. Since this is a ColdFusion UI and not your own it is difficult to just update the API calls. Which is why it is recommended to use your own. It's a simple fix with jQuery UI but not really ColdFusion UI.

6) Also, a lot of ColdFusion UI messes with your headers. For example, . This tag has been known to break mobile sites and other headers because it adds its own headers to your HTML page. 

7) cfinput required="" is conflict with the HTML 5 input required=""

Comment: There's a github project that shows superior, more flexible alternatives to many of the coldfusion ui controls: https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way with background reading here: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/1/23/Im-not-going-to-tell-you-to-stop-using-ColdFusion-UI-tags-anymore

Comment: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2014/1/23/Im-not-going-to-tell-you-to-stop-using-ColdFusion-UI-tags-anymore

Comment: @Antony you beat me to it :p

Comment: Neither of those links address the question.

Comment: @DanBracuk Let's see, it says "Things like cfgrid, cfpod, etc, are easy to use, but in general lead to far more trouble than they are worth. " and also provides alternative solutions... how does that NOT address the question?

Comment: @ Digital Chris, I already have read that Ray's post. I know alternatives are available. But why? They cause problems. What problems? That is what I know. If I am not wrong one of them was it exposes CFIDE in some way or other causing security issues. Not sure. That is why I asked the question. What problem/s it causes so that I can convince someone to not use it.

Comment: Read comments further down the page: "...if you want to do something weird with it, you have more power having your own solution as opposed to cfgrid which may lock you in. (Or, when you upgrade, your code may stop working.)" This is why. CF UI tags generate code for you, but only in ways the tag authors envision. If you use it, and later requirements change, you may be stuck with writing a kludge to work *around* your UI tag, or abandoning it and starting from scratch.

Comment: Here is another resource for you from Ben Forta's Blog - [When Using ColdFusion (Client Functions) No Longer Makes Sense](http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense).

Comment: @DigitalChris, a generic statement of causing problems does not answer this question.  It asks "what problems".

Comment: @DanBracuk please see my other quote from the same page. Also, if it *answered* the question, it would be in the answer box. I provided it more for supportive evidence and possible solutions.

Comment: Here's my take on the "ColdFusion UI the Right Way" project: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/01/oi-you-bloody-wankers-stop-using.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issues with the UI tags built-in to CF are:

- Were written by people who are not CFML developers.
- Were written by people who are not HTML/JS developers.
- They use old outdated versions of JavaScript libraries and HTML.
- They have caused security issues in the past.
- They get in the way of knowing how things actually work.
- They don't have documentation comparable to the average JS library.
- The Flash and XML versions of cfform were especially difficult to work with.

And possibly a few other reasons that have slipped my mind.

If you have old code that uses them, and the code works acceptably, then you're unlikely to get shot for not changing it - assuming there are no further undiscovered security issues, obviously.
(Though of course, whether the code *does* actually work acceptably or has simply been put up with may be a matter of debate.)

If you're working on new code, you should learn to use modern UI libraries that are written by actual JS developers who understand browsers, libraries that are far more widely tested and documented, that you can understand how they work, that put you in control of what's being done, and so on.

Comment: I would add 1) `<cfinput required="">` is conflict with the HTML 5 `<input required="">`  2) Flash forms have a whole step of problems of their own.

Comment: A bit unsure about the Flash point - I mean, you're not wrong, but ideally it should be explained a bit more (that's the point here; not just saying "it's bad", but saying _why_). I remember Flash Forms (and XML) were difficult to do styling/etc, but never really wasted much time with them so can't say much more - if anyone has it would be good to expand that point.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of giving you a link to the solution to a problem that is unknown to @CFML_Developer I will simply briefly explain the issues I've had and other have had with ColdFusion UI.

ColdFusion UI does work currently. However, the issue people have is simply, technology changes. It's simple as that really. jQuery and other UIs are constantly changing. Along with a lot of other APIs that ColdFusion UI uses. This means, if you are using ColdFusion 10 today and 5 years from now you are on ColdFusion 13 you may have issues with your ColdFusion 10's UI.

Another example is `<cfmap>`. `<cfmap>` had an issue recently because it uses google maps and google updated their API. Since the update took place it broke the `<cfmap>`tag. Since this is a ColdFusion UI and not your own it is difficult to just update the API calls. Which is why it is recommended to use your own. It's a simple fix with jQuery UI but not really ColdFusion UI.

Also, a lot of ColdFusion UI messes with your headers. For example, `<cfform>`. This tag has been known to break mobile sites and other headers because it adds its own headers to your HTML page.

Finally, I personally find all ColdFusion UI more difficult to work with than actual jQuery UI. Just because with jQuery UI you can be specific to your needs and it's a lot more flexible to work with. Honestly, it's also faster to do if you understand jQuery.

Comment: In ColdFusion 10, `cfchart` is more difficult to use and customize than if you use ZingChart directly.

Comment: @ScottStroz I'm sure we can make a giant list of UI tags that are more difficult to use than a jQuery plugin. =P